# How to exclude multiple file extensions in tree?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tree

When using the tree command, I'd like to exclude listing `*.png` and `*.svg` from the output. The problem is that every bracket expansion I try doesn't work. Is it because of how tree processes commandline arguments?

```
tree -I *.{svg,png}
tree -I '*.{svg,png}'
tree -I '{*.svg,*.png}'
tree -I '{*.svg,*.png}'
tree -I '*.{p,s}(v,n}g'
tree -I '*.{svg|png}'
```

Specs:

- GNU bash, version 4.4.23
- tree v1.7.0

Comment: @Attie solved this for me in https://superuser.com/a/1354169/939457
The answer is `tree -I '*.svg|*.png'` 
Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-I` is the inverse of `-P`... the manual gives more information on what is acceptable for the latter:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

> ```
> -P pattern
> ```
>
> List only those files that match the wild-card pattern.
>
> Note: you must use the `-a` option to also consider those files beginning with a dot `.` for matching.
>
> Valid wildcard operators are `*` (any zero or more characters), `?` (any single character), `[...]` (any single character listed between brackets (optional `-` (dash) for character range may be used: ex: `[A-Z]`), and `[^...]` (any single character not listed in brackets) and `|` separates alternate patterns.

There's no mention of the shell's [brace expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BRACEEXPREF) syntax of `{a,b}`... This expansion is handled by `tree`, not `bash`.

And unfortunately you can't specify `-I` multiple times...

Instead you need to list the full patterns with a pipe (`|`) to separate them:

```
tree -I '*.svg|*.png'
```

Note the use of single quotes to prevent the shell from expanding the asterisk (`*`) or variables (introduced by a dollar - `$`).

---

Note also that it's not even possible to coerce the shell's brace expansion, as shown below:

```
$ tree -I '*.'{svg,png}
+ tree -I '*.svg' '*.png'
*.png [error opening dir]
```